# Delete files if number exceeds 30 in number for different files in same directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, file-management

The folder gets populated some jobs that run daily, weekly or monthly. 
For eg. daily job outputs be like:

```
daily-2017-16-08.txt
daily-2017-15-08.txt
```

Weekly be like:

```
weekly-2017-01-08.txt
weekly-2017-08-08.txt
```

and monthly is like:

```
monthly-2017-01-08.txt
monthly-2017-01-07.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if number exceeds 30 days" ?

Comment: I meant 30 in number not days. Sorry about that.

Comment: You mean 2nd field which is representing date like `16`,`15`,`01` should not be exceeded number 30 ?

Comment: total number of daily should not exceed 30, similarly for weekly and monthly

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE_TYPE in daily weekly monthly 
do
     COUNTER=0
     for FILE in $(ls -t ${FILE_TYPE}-*)
     do
        let COUNTER++
        [ ${COUNTER} -gt 30 ] && rm ${FILE}
     done
done
```

Comment: see: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/74329)

Comment: Updated to not parse ls output as recommended by @Cyrus

Comment: Is there a way to modify your code so that it automatically takes different file types, without me specifying it?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand what you mean by "automatically takes" but you could change the `for` line to look like `for FILE_TYPE in $@` and then you call the shell script like `cleanupProgram.sh daily weekly monthly` in cron and if you ever wanted to add or remove file types you just modify the cron entry.